# Rails 3 => Undefined method 'array' when I try to rake db:migrate

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, scaffold, dbmigrate

This is my first post here so go easy. I am trying to build my first app in Rails 3.2.1. I am trying to generate a scaffold for Paint using the following terminal command:

```
rails generate scaffold Paint paint_family:string paint_hex:array paint_available:boolean     paint_location:integer paint_quantity:integer paint_additional_info:text
```

But when I try to migrate I get the following error:

```
undefined method `array' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x007fbd8bdb1c58>
```

Here is the migration record:

```
  class CreatePaints < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :paints do |t|
    t.string :paint_family
    t.array :paint_hex
    t.boolean :paint_available
    t.integer :paint_location
    t.integer :paint_quantity
    t.text :paint_additional_info

    t.timestamps
 end
 end
```

end

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is. But that's because I don't know what I'm doing.  Any advice/help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
t.array :paint_hex
```

There is no column type called `array`. You can use `string` or `text` and then serialize the value if you really want to save an array.

```
class Paint < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :paint_hex
end
```

*Just by the way*: Prefixing all your attribute names with `paint_` is a pretty uncommon naming scheme for a rails application.

Comment: Then give me an upvote and select my answer as the correct one. That's how we show appreciation on stackoverflow...

Answer (score 10):

In Rails 4 and using PostgreSQL you can actually use an array type in the DB:

Migration:

```
class CreateSomething < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :something do |t|
      t.string :some_array, array: true, default: []
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Array its not a valid database type. You cant create a column with type array.

There is some ways to store an array in a field. Check the [**serialize**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class) method.
You must declare the column of type **text** and the in the class specify that the columns serializas an object of type array